# Max RAM for 32 bit windows on 64 bit machine?

Tags: memory

I have read many posts about maximum RAM with 32 and 64 machine systems/machine and still not clear on the answer. It is not clear if systems mean hardware or windows itself. Soooo...

Can i use more than 4 gig of RAM on a 64 bit architecture computer that is running 32 bit Windows 10 ?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/280780/what-is-the-theoretical-memory-limit-for-32-bits-apps-running-through-wow64) explains the reason the limit is 3GB.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/830594/ram-patch-for-windows-7-32bit) also helps.  This question shows a lack of research, every 64-bit processor that Windows 10 runs on, is actually a 32-bit processor that simply supports the 64-but x86 architecture extension developed by AMD

Answer (score 1):

No. For regular workstations, if you have a 32-bit Operating System, you are limited to 3 GB of memory or a bit more. Most workstations cannot readily manage PAE Extensions to use a more memory in a 32-bit OS (Servers more often will have PAE extensions), so just upgrade to a 64-bit OS to solve your issue. That works great.